# Will resetting my database affect other sites on my multisite Wordpress install?

Tags: multisite, database, reset

I am using the Bridge theme and after installing a theme I would now like to change to a different demo theme. In the [instruction video provided by Qode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3YTwvTX5CA) it advises that I use a plugin called [wordpress database reset](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-database-reset/). I would like to know if resetting my database by using this plugin will affect the installation of Wordpress on my other sites that I have installed within the Wordpress multisite set up?

Answer (score 0):

If they all use the same database then I would imagine so.

Do you really need to reset your database when importing a new code though?

Comment: No I guess not. Qode probably advise that as it is a easy solution to give people to solve the issue. I wouldn't know where to start to do it manually.

Comment: I've used many themes in the past and never needed to clear my databases to import a demo. As long as there's back ups of your database then you can always give it a go but I would advise against it as like I said I've never needed to touch a database when importing theme demos.